# Bootstrap product grid alignment error

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can somebody help on how to solve [this](https://storetest.domec.tools/Catalog/SearchByType?typeID=7) alignment error on the last line?

It only seems to happen on `md` and `lg` screens.

Comment: I didnt downvote you. I checked it but cant figure it out. Somehow 'Buono Regalo Amazon da 500 euro' s height must be a bit higher then 'Regala l'emozione di un volo unita alla possibilità di scegliere la meta (euro 100)' preventing 'Regala l'emozione di un volo unita alla possibilità di scegliere la meta (euro 200)' to float left

Comment: yes 'Buono Regalo Amazon da 500 euro' s  height is 424.95 and 'Regala l'emozione di un volo unita alla possibilità di scegliere la meta (euro 100)' s height and after is 424.84. 
Why? I dont know

Comment: Got it: your images are not the same height. (not the same dimensions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap clearfix every 3 columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278203/bootstrap-clearfix-every-3-columns)

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because all your div's have the same height except at the bottom. Try giving a min-height to all your product div's.

Try something like this:

```
.row.illustration-v2.margin-bottom-30 > div {
    min-height: 450px;
}
```

Depending on the dimensions of your product image and title, etc, change the min-height.